# Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu linux: creating a new class throws db error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu

I am a novice linux user trying to come to terms with *nix development using Ruby on Rails.  I am reading an excellent book titled "Simply Rails 2" [SitePoint:lenz] and haven't had any problem until I try to create a new Story object within the rails console and I get a "no driver for sqlite3 found" error:

$sudo ruby script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.2)

> > class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
> >     end
> >     => nil
> >     story = Story.new
> >     RuntimeError:  no driver for sqlite3 found from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.0/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.4/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:621 :in 'load_driver'...

I think it may have someting to do with where I installed the Ruby components.
I installed these folders on my desktop:

ruby-1.9.0-5
rubygems-1.3.1
sqlite-3.6.11

I'm pretty sure this is a configuration/installation issue but I'm so lost when it comes to Linux and would so appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only recommend to install gem via your distribution package manager (aptitude/apt-get on Debian, yum on Fedora, ...) and then install everything via gem itself.

```
gem install rails
```

This should include the sqlite driver.

Comment: rails and sqlite are installed already.  I think it's  due to there being multiple versions of rails and/or sqlite.

Comment: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games.  
I'm wondering if I shouldn't move the sqlite-3.6.11 and/or rubygems-1.3.1 and/or ruby-1.9.0-5 folders to /usr/local/bin.  can I just move them there?  I'm sure they don't belong on the desktop.